# Is it possible to make xsl:template sensitive to the pushed-from node without using xsl:param?

Tags: xslt

I'm pretty sure the answer to this is no, but since the only alternative is what I deem inelegant code, I thought I'd throw this out and see if I'm missing something while hoping this hasn't been asked.

Given this source XML:

```
<root>
    <p>Hello world</p>
    <move elem="content" item="test"/>
    <p>Another text node.</p>
    <content item="test">I can't <b>figure</b> this out.</content>
</root>
```

I want this result:

```
<root>
    <block>Hello world</block>
    <newContent>I can't <hmmm>figure</hmmm> this out.</newContent>
    <block>Another text node.</block>
</root>
```

An ordinary language description:

1. Replace <move .../> with the result of processing
   the element whose name matches move's @elem attribute and whose @item
   matches move's @item attribute (e.g., in this case the content of the element [<content>] is processed so <b> is replaced by <hmm>).
2. Prevent the element from step 1 from
   being written out to the result tree in its original document order

The problem is the input XML document will be considerably more complex and variable. And the stylesheet is a third-party transform that I am extending. The template I'd have to copy in order to use a mode-based solution is pretty significant in size and that seems inelegant to me. I know, for example, this would work:

```
<xsl:template match="b">
    <hmmm>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </hmmm>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="p">
    <block>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </block>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="move">
    <xsl:variable name="elem" select="@elem"/>
    <xsl:variable name="item" select="@item"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//*[name()=$elem and @item=$item]" mode="copy-and-process"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="content"/>
<xsl:template match="content" mode="copy-and-process">
            <newContent><xsl:apply-templates/></newContent>
</xsl:template>
```

What I would like to do is have the <xsl:template> that matches "content" be sensitive to what node pushes to it. So, that I can have an <xsl:template match="content"/> that is only executed (and therefore its matching node and children are suppressed) when the node pushed from is <root> and not <move>. The virtue in this is that if the third-party stylesheet's relevant template is updated, I don't have to worry about updating a copy of the stylesheet that processes the <content> node. I'm pretty sure this isn't possible, but I thought it was worth asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simply do**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:key name="kMover" match="move" use="concat(@elem,'+',@item)"/>

 <xsl:key name="kToMove" match="*" use="concat(name(),'+',@item)"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="move">
  <newContent>
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="move" select=
       "key('kToMove', concat(@elem,'+',@item))/node()"/>
  </newContent>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="p">
  <block><xsl:apply-templates/></block>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="b" mode="move">
  <hmmm><xsl:apply-templates/></hmmm>
 </xsl:template>
 <xsl:template match="*[key('kMover', concat(name(),'+',@item))]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<root>
    <p>Hello world</p>
    <move elem="content" item="test"/>
    <p>Another text node.</p>
    <content item="test">I can't <b>figure</b> this out.</content>
</root>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced:**

```
<root>
   <block>Hello world</block>
   <newContent>I can't <hmmm>figure</hmmm> this out.</newContent>
   <block>Another text node.</block>
</root>
```

Comment: Not having a proper understanding of xsl:key bites me in the butt once again. Thanks!

Comment: I believe this can be simplified by (a) removing the `move` mode altogether and (b) changing the last template to merely be `<xsl:template match="content" />` (which eliminates the need for the `kMover` key), yes?

Comment: @ABach, You may not have understood the question -- there is no guarantee that the elements defined by a `move` element, will be named `content`.

Comment: Ah yes, got it. Thanks. I still don't understand why the `move` mode is present, however. Remove it and your solution still works as expected...